# Run configuration on specific set of agents?

Tags: teamcity

We're using TeamCity 9 and have a pool of agents, only some of which can run a particular job we've created.  It's going to be a while before a new pool can be created with new agents, and in the meantime we would like to set this job to run only on specific ones.

In the configuration settings we can choose `system.agent.name`, but that only allows us one agent.  Is there a way to configure things so that I can run on multiple agents based on their name, so that, say `teamcity_agent01`, `teamcity_agent07` and `teamcity_agent12` are eligible?

Answer (score 1):

If the capabilities you want on the agent expose environment variables you can have a command line step refer to the environment variable and that will scope the job to a suitable agent.

e.g.

```
echo "%env.PATH_TO_GIT%"
```

You can add environment variables to your agents [like this](https://samarthrastogi.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/configure-teamcity-in-10-minutes/)

> open file “/conf/buildAgent.properties” at agent
>   system. This file contains parameters in key=value format.
>
> To add a system properties add line like -> system.os=Linux
>
> To add an environment variable  add line like ->
>   env.JAVA_HOME=/home/java/jdk1.6.0_13 the

The beauty of this is that as you add more capabilities and agents then you don't need to revisit each job to change where it can run

Comment: Excellent point. It requires more setup but this is the way to go. Some of our build agents are our own dev machines and we have to restrict when TC can use these agents. Preferably when no one is at work.

Answer (score 0):

**For Teamcity 9.x**

1. Next to the Projects, and Changes select Agents.
2. Select the agent that you want to run specific jobs on.
3. Select the "Compatible Configurations" tab.
4. On the "Current run configuration policy" dropdown select "Run assgined configurations only"
5. Click on the "+ Assign configuration" button.
6. Compatible configurations are colored blue. Select as you wish.

The timing of the configurations and when they should run can be configured under each build configuration triggers tab.